# How to prevent embedded video from linking to another web page

Tags: html, css, video-streaming, html5-video

I have an embedded video on my webpage that is not from youtube or vimeo. I want the viewer to only watch the video on my webpage. How do I prevent the video from linking to another webpage when it's clicked? I used the CSS property of pointer-events: none to stop the video from linking to another webpage but now the video will not play on my webpage. Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

iframe {
     pointer-events: none;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>    
<iframe   src="http://flashservice.simplevideo.com/embedframe/18598" frameborder=0 width=510 height=400 scrolling=no allowfullscreen  ></iframe>   

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: share your video url , that url is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sandbox` attribute for iFrames should be what you're looking for.
For example:

```
<iframe src="http://flashservice.simplevideo.com/embedframe/18598"
frameborder=0 width=510 height=400 scrolling=no allowfullscreen 
sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts"></iframe>
```

Note that the `sandbox` attribute acts as a whitelist, so by not giving it the `allow-popups` or `allow-top-navigation` permissions, it cannot open a new page, nor change the parent webpage!

Comment: @CarlMax Then please click the tick to accept my answer - you get reputation too for doing so!